# How to output an alert message when something changes in the directory (FileWatcher)?

Tags: javascript, c#, file-watcher

I made a FileWatcher to control if something happens in a specific (path) directory. Now if something happens i want to output an alert message with the filename which was created or renamed, in the JavaScript file. But i don't know how to solve this problem.

How do i have to use the methods in the HomeController to get the name of the file in JavaScript? Or do i have to make a new method?

```
//FileWatcher.cs
public class FileWatcherService
    {
        public event EventHandler<string> FileCreated;
        public event EventHandler<string> FileDeleted;
        public event EventHandler<RenamedEventArgs> FileRenamed;

        public FileWatcherService()
        {
            FileSystemWatcher fileWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher();

            string path = @"C:\Users\Kopuz\Desktop\Log-Dateien\";
            fileWatcher.Path = path;

            fileWatcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess
                | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
                | NotifyFilters.FileName
                | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName
                | NotifyFilters.CreationTime;

            fileWatcher.Deleted += OnDeleted;
            fileWatcher.Created += OnCreated;
            fileWatcher.Renamed += OnRenamed;

            fileWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        }

        private void OnCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"File: {e.Name} created on {e.FullPath}");
            FileCreated.Invoke(this, e.FullPath);
        }

        private void OnDeleted(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"File: {e.Name} deleted from {e.FullPath}");
            FileDeleted?.Invoke(this, e.FullPath);
        }

        private void OnRenamed(object sender, RenamedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"File: {e.OldName} renamed to {e.Name}");
            FileRenamed?.Invoke(this, e);
        }
    }
```

```
//HomeController.cs
public HomeController(PerformanceAnalyseToolContext db, FileWatcherService fws)
        {
            this.db = db;
            fws.FileRenamed += FileWatcherService_FileRenamed;
            fws.FileCreated += FileWatcherService_FileCreated;
            fws.FileDeleted += FileWatcherService_FileDeleted;
        }

        private void FileWatcherService_FileDeleted(object sender, string fullPath)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"HomeController::File deleted: {fullPath}");
        }

        private void FileWatcherService_FileCreated(object sender, string fullPath)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"HomeController::File created: {fullPath}");

            string fileName = new FileInfo(fullPath).Name;
            Console.WriteLine(fileName);
        }

        private void FileWatcherService_FileRenamed(object sender, RenamedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"HomeController::File renamed: {e.OldFullPath} --> {e.FullPath}");

            string fileName = new FileInfo(e.FullPath).Name;
            Console.WriteLine(fileName);
        }
```

Comment: The controller lives only shortly, it cannot be used for consuming the events. You could create a background worker that would subscribe to the `FileWatcherService` for the file events and keep track of the changes, then the controller could look at the changes.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do either polling, which is usually frowned upon.

or a websocket type deal for always connected push capable two-way communications of this sort.
https://blog.stanko.io/do-you-really-need-websockets-343aed40aa9b

Live push updates is what websockets were made for.